# Medialize/sass.js is it possible modify sass variables?

Tags: javascript, css, sass

I want to know if there is a method that permits to change sass vars in The browser and see live changing.
In less.js there is this method called "modifyVars".
Is there a similar functionality in sass.js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Less uses lazy loading and last declaration wins for variables so you can put the definition of the variables to override afterwards with "modifyVars";

With Sass you can override only variables defined with `!default`. You can override these variables by putting their definition at the start of your code.

```
Sass.writeFile('code.scss', '$var: red !default; p { color: $var; }');
Sass.compile('$var: green; @import "code.scss";', function(result) {
  console.log(result);
});
```

Should compile into:

```
p { 
color: green; }
```